# Get AppStore application ID before submitting application

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a new application idea that requires to get the App Store application ID right after application was created in iTunesConnect and first build was already uploaded. This operation should be executed without human interaction (I will make a script to get this info)

Is there a way to do it?

I tried to use App Store API but didn't work: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.something.else . It works for already submitted apps and for older that are not necessarily submitted.

App Store API resource: https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#lookup

Comment: you can't get AppID without creating it in iTunesConnect. what's the problem with it?

Comment: You can only get your own App ID (which is different from Bundle ID), once your app is created in iTunes Connect. But it's not possible to get "all" App ID, i.e. even from other developers' not yet submitted apps.

Comment: @heximal: As I already wrote, I create iTunesConnect application, I upload an .ipa and after this I want to get Apple Store ID. All this steps are made from the command line using the API.

Comment: @Oddie: This is what I am already doing, I use the bundle id for making that call and normally I get a JSON response with apps infos including, where key 'trackId' contains app store id. But for new apps that I have tested with I receive: {
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}. Is there a possibility that the application wasn't already indexed?

Comment: @meeshoo The App Store API only contains public data (i.e. gone through review and stuff). Even than it lags a little bit behind. So it's not possible to get it via the API. You could scrap iTunes Connect if you are trying to get your own apps info. If you're familiar with Ruby, had over to Fastlane, which surfaces lots of iTunes Connect info: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane

Comment: @Oddie, yes I am already using parts of fastlane, I will dig more. And yes, I checked better with my apps and it's only working for live ones. Thanks a lot!